# Does Google Cloud Storage client in Python check CRC (or MD5) automatically?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, integrity

I have tried to find out if [GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) Python client, and more specifically, [`blob.upload_from_file()`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.upload_from_file) and [`blob.download_to_file()`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.download_to_file) check integrity of the uploaded or downloaded file automatically. If not, how can I check the CRC hash programmatically? Any pointers to documentation or source code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit(06/29/22)
Checksums in Python are now available for md5 and crc32c for uploads and downloads.

For example: Blob.download_as_bytes() has a new parameter named checksum with three values (None, 'md5', 'crc32c')
https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.download_as_bytes